# XQuery: how to concatenate two constructors in return?

Tags: xquery

I have a function which contains a constructor:

```
declare function local:Construct ($id)
{
  <tag id="{$id}"/>
}
```

I use the function in return of "FLWOR":

```
for $val in ...
...
return local:Construct(data($val/id))
```

This works.

Now I want to concatenate two Constructs like this

```
for $val in ...
...
return local:Construct(data($val/id1)) + local:Construct(data($val/id2))
```

The plus sign is of course wrong. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to return two nodes for each *$val*, in which case you want to use the **,** operator, like so:

```
for $val in ...
...
return (local:Construct(data($val/id1)), local:Construct(data($val/id2)))
```

The extra brackets are required, or you will be trying to concatenate `local:Construct(data($val/id2))` onto the result of the FLWOR, which would result in an "undefined variable" error.